# Convert an arbitrary string to xml in ruby

Tags: xml, ruby, string

If I have a string which may contain any characters (including '/', '&',etc...) how do convert it safely into XML that can be stored like this:

```
<myelement>mystring</myelement>
```

Does it need to be CDATA, or can I easily convert it using a ruby function?

Comment: Sorry Jonas, I put the xml in the text and it got removed; lesson learned; had to place it in a code block ;-)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

In Ruby 1.9.2 to escape XML special characters in Strings, use the 'encode' method.

Example, if you have:

```
my_string = 'this is "my" complicated <String>'
```

For **XML attributes** use:

```
"<node attr=#{my_string.encode(:xml => :attr)} />"
```

Generates:

```
<node attr="this is &quot;my&quot; complicated &lt;String&gt;" />
```

For **XML text** use:

```
"<node>#{my_string.encode(:xml => :text)}</node>"
```

Generates:

```
<node>this is "my" complicated &lt;String&gt;</node>
```

Answer (score 6):

```
require 'rexml/document'
doc = REXML::Document.new
root = doc.add_element "Alpha"
root.add_text "now is & the < time > ' for \" me"
doc.write
```

Produces:

```
<Alpha>now is &amp; the &lt; time &gt; &apos; for &quot; me</Alpha>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not escape all the XML-invalid symbols. For example, `\v`

Answer (score 5):

The CGI module has an escapeHTML method.

```
CGI.escapeHTML("&<>")
#=> "&amp;&lt;&gt;"
```

Comment: I think it's better to specifically use XML escape rather than HTML escape methods.

Comment: It doesn't escape ASCII control characters.

Answer (score 4):

This answer is mostly for Rails, but, however, might be useful. I looked up how rails `.to_xml` works and found out you can use `Builder::XChar#encode` from `builder` gem.

```
Builder::XChar.encode(%(this is "my" complicated <String>\v))
#=> "this is \"my\" complicated &lt;String&gt;�"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a library in ruby called REXML for working with xml.
It might be useful for what you need. Here's a link to a tutorial.
http://www.germane-software.com/software/rexml/docs/tutorial.html

Comment: would be better if more detail provided to solve the question.